Custom Compose waitUntilAtLeastOneExists message on fail
In the compose test, I use this function to wait until some node with matcher appear
@ExperimentalTestApi
fun ComposeUiTest.waitUntilNodeCount(
    matcher: SemanticsMatcher,
    count: Int,
    timeoutMillis: Long
): Unit

On fail it throws a ComposeTimeoutException with generic message:

ComposeTimeoutException the condition is not satisfied after [timeoutMillis].

The message is not informative, and it's annoying every time to look at the full stack trace to see what went wrong.
Is there any way to change this message, to show what conditions were not satisfied? For example, if some node does not exist, it will print  :

ComposeTimeoutException Node with $matcher does not exist after [timeoutMillis].

Thanks in advance!

Hey, did the solution proposed below work for you?

@BenjyTec
Hi, sorry for the late answer - yeah, it works as intended.

Have a look at the official source code of the waitUntilNodeCount function. It calls waitUntil under the hood. The waitUntil function offers a parameter where you can provide a textual description that should be included in the Exception when thrown.
Please try to create your own testing function as follows:
fun ComposeUiTest.waitUntilNodeCountWithMessage(
    message: String? = null,
    matcher: SemanticsMatcher,
    count: Int,
    timeoutMillis: Long = 1_000L
) {
    waitUntil(message, timeoutMillis) {
        onAllNodes(matcher).fetchSemanticsNodes().size == count
    }
}

Now, use this instead of the default waitUntilNodeCount and provide a message. Please report back whether that message is indeed included in the Exception text.
composeTestRule.waitUntilNodeCountWithMessage("Hello World", /*...*/)

